# Rotating div with css

Tags: html, css

Hello I am wondering how to rotate div like from upside down to 45 dg left so content go from left to right. And to rotate content divs as well 45dg to right so it looks something like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    HELLO                HOW ARE YOU?

                 HI!                      GOOD AND U?

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Words got rotated to right and div got rotated to left

DONE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{



}


#myDiv {
width: 200px;
    height: 400px;

    border: 1px solid black;
margin-left: 100px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(270deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
#sasa{
    margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(90deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div id="myDiv">
<div id="sasa">Hello</div><div id="sasa">Hello</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rotate [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

```
<div class="rotated">Hello World</div>
```

Css:

```
.rotated {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
              transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: It wont work i am trying on w3schools editor and I cant see my div with text... I have rotated first div and divs inside but there is no text showing ...

Comment: I did it and it is very complicated with margins when you rotate